# Error 20599 Cannot open SQL Server using VB6/Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6, odbc

I have been trying to browse a SQL Server database-based [Crystal Reports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_Reports) version 8 with following Visual Basic code:

```
CrystalReport1.ReportFileName = "C:\Report1.rpt"
CrystalReport1.Destination = crptToWindow
CrystalReport1.DiscardSavedData = True
CrystalReport1.WindowState = crptMaximized
MsgBox "Ok!", vbInformation
CrystalReport1.Action = 1
```

I am using the Crystal Reports control. The database of the report is `ODBC datasource` connecting to SQL Server. Without `DiscardSavedData` this works, but it displays old data. With `DiscardSavedData`, I get the error message:

> - Error 20599 Cannot open SQL Server.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you set the connection information in your code?  Have a look at this post, it might help you http://p2p.wrox.com/pro-vb-databases/11987-error-20599-cannot-open-sql-server.html

Comment: I didn't specify which connection info, it is the CrystalReport1,Connect = the DSN / Connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved my issus by adding the connection string  `CrystalReport1.Connect`, i'd like to share my solution for all.

```
 CrystalReport1.ReportFileName = "C:\Report1.rpt"
    CrystalReport1.Destination = crptToWindow
    CrystalReport1.DiscardSavedData = True
    CrystalReport1.Connect ="Data Source=Localhost;UID=sa;PWD=****;DSQ=Dat BdName;"
    CrystalReport1.WindowState = crptMaximized
CrystalReport1.Action = 1
```